# Происхождение слова "завзятый"

Tags: этимология

Внезапно подумалось: а каково происхождение слова "завзятый" в выражениях, например, "завзятый игрок"?

Answer (score 2):

> В составе лексики русского
> литературного языка находится
> некоторое количество украинизмов и
> белоруссизмов. Эта родственная примесь
> до сих пор еще не подвергалась
> тщательному историко-лингвистическому
> анализу. Разные слои ее не выделены. В
> некоторых случаях «странность»
> морфологической структуры славянского
> слова выдает его невеликорусский тип.
>
> Слово завзятый, свойственное
> разговорному стилю современной
> литературной речи, употребляется в
> значении: `настоящий, истый,
> страстный, с увлечением предающийся
> чему-нибудь, отчаянный', напр.,
> завзятый игрок, завзятая сплетница,
> завзятый спорщик.
>
> Слово завзятый применяется в узком
> кругу фразеологических сочетаний. Оно
> является эмоционально-усилительным
> эпитетом только тех имен
> существительных, относящихся к
> категории лица, которые имеют
> качественно-характеристическое
> значение, напр., театрал, балетоман,
> шахматист и т. п.
>
> По своей морфологической структуре
> слово завзятый кажется причастием от
> глагола завзять. Но такого глагола нет
> в русском литературном языке (ср.
> забрать). Между тем в украинском и
> белорусском языке соответствующее
> слово входит в большое лексическое
> гнездо родственных образований.
> Например, в «Словаре белорусского
> наречия» И. И. Носовича находим:
> «Завзятный, прил. Гордый, заносчивый,
> неуступчивый. Якийты завзятный, тобеи
> слова не скажи. Завзя́то, нареч.
> Заносчиво, отважно, гордо. Завзято
> поступив. Завзятосць, и, с, ж.
> Заносчивость, смелость, дерзость.
> Откульу его такая завзятосць берецца,
> штоникого не боицца.
>
> Завзятый, прил. Чванный, дерзкий,
> заносчивый. Завзятому нечего и
> говориць гетаго.Завзятый толькисебе
> видзиць.Завзяценький, прил. смягч.
> `Щекотливенький'. Завзяценький
> норовець.
>
> Завзяцьца, сов. глагола возвр.
> Забирацьца.— 1) Почувствовать силу
> свою'. Завзявся, якпобогацев. 2)
> `Зазнаться, стать дерзким'. Завзявся,
> нос задрав» (Носович, Сл. блр. нареч.,
> с. 162). Ср. украинск. завзятий,
> завзяття смелость, упорство,
> выдержка.
>
> Слово завзятый не было
> зарегистрировано ни одним словарем
> русского литературного языка до
> словаря В. И. Даля. Даль приводит это
> слово как областное, южное и западное
> (т. е. как употребительное лишь в
> народных говорах, близких к
> украинскому и белорусскому языкам). И
> значение этого слова, отмеченное
> Далем, свойственно, главным образом,
> украинскому и белорусскому языкам:
> `бойкий, предприимчивый, который
> постоит за себя (сл. Даля 1880, 1, с.
> 576). Украинскому завзятий (ср.
> украинское завзяття — смелость,
> отвага, выдержка, упорство),
> белорусскому заўзя́тый соответствует
> польское zawzity с тем же кругом
> значений.
>
> В русской литературе слово завзятый
> впервые появляется в конце XVIII в. —
> начале XIX в. в языке писателей
> украинского происхождения — в значении
> `бесстрашный, отважный, настойчивый,
> упорный'. У В. Т. Нарежного в
> «Бурсаке»: «Он в жару восторга
> обещался подготовить еще человек пять,
> шесть из самых завзятых» [т. е.
> смелых, отважных. — В. В.] (ч. 4, гл.
> 9). В повести О. М. Сомова «Гайдамак»
> (1825 г.): «”Какой завзятый чумак!
> какой лихой парень, какой статный и
> пригожий мужчина! какой богатый и
> тароватый!“, — раздавалось отовсюду»
> (см. Русск. старина, 1883, т. 39,
> июль, с. 87). У Гоголя в «Тарасе
> Бульбе»: «Демид Попович тоже перешел
> туда, потому что был сильно завзятого
> нрава козак — не мог долго высидеть на
> месте» (ч. 8). У Н. И. Костомарова в
> «Богдане Хмельницком»: «...сам
> Хмельницкий, проезжая по рядам своих
> завзятых молодцов, говорил им не
> длинные речи, а коротко напоминал им,
> что они воюют за веру» (Костомаров,
> Богдан Хмельницкий, т. 2, гл. 4).
>
> Влившись в словарь русского
> литературного языка, слово завзятый
> расценивается как народно-областное,
> получает ироническую окраску и
> расширяет контексты своего
> употребления. Соответственно новой
> экспрессии и новому употреблению
> изменяется и общее значение этого
> слова. Оно становится в один
> синонимический ряд с такими словами,
> как отъявленный, сущий, настоящий80.
> Например, у Салтыкова-Щедрина: «Все
> наклонности завзятой приживалки:
> празднословие, льстивая угодливость
> ради подачки, прожорливость — росли с
> изумительной быстротой» («Господа
> Головлевы»). У Тургенева в «Нови»:
> «Обхватив по модному большой белый
> хлеб обеими руками и переламывая его
> пополам над тарелкой супа, как это
> делают завзятые парижане в ”Café
> riche“...» (гл. 14). У Тургенева же в
> очерке «Пэгаз» (1871): «У меня, как у
> всякого завзятого охотника, перебывало
> много собак, дурных, хороших и
> отличных». У Станюковича в «Омуте»: «С
> опытностью завзятого дипломата он не
> показывал и вида, что замечает
> перемену».
>
> Эти экспрессивно-семантические
> изменения в употреблении слова
> завзятый происходили в русском
> литературном языке с 40—50-х годов XIX
> в.
>
> Статья опубликована в «Докладах и
> сообщениях» филологического факультета
> МГУ, вып. 3 (М., 1947) вместе со
> статьями о словах никчемный, отщепенец
> под общим заглавием «Из истории
> русской литературной лексики. (К
> вопросу об исторических связях
> русского, украинского и белорусского
> языков)». Публикации предпослана
> вводная часть, в которой сказано:
> «Языки единой восточно-славянской
> ветви — русский, украинский,
> белорусский, связанные между собою
> тесными братскими отношениями,
> находились (и находятся) на протяжении
> всей своей истории в самом близком
> культурном взаимодействии. Они щедро
> делились друг с другом культурными
> достижениями и идейными ценностями.
> Конечно, сильнее и разнообразнее было,
> особенно со второй трети XVIII века,
> влияние русского языка как языка
> наиболее передового и развитого, на
> процессы развития и обогащения
> украинского и белорусского языков. Но
> и для истории русского языка это живое
> общение с украинским и белорусским
> языками было в высшей степени
> плодотворно. В словарную сокровищницу
> русского литературного языка внесли
> свой вклад и украинский и белорусский
> языки. Вот несколько иллюстраций из
> истории русской литературной лексики».
>
> В архиве сохранилась рукопись (на 4-х
> листках ветхой бумаги, написанных в
> разное время) и старая машинописная
> копия с авторской правкой. Печатается
> по оттиску, сверенному с авторской
> рукописью, с внесением ряда
> необходимых поправок и уточнений. — М.
> Л.
>
> 80 Любопытно, что и в областных
> народных русских говорах
> (владимирских, саратовских,
> устюженских) слово завзятый имеет ту
> же окраску и то же значение.
>
> **В. В. Виноградов. История слов, 2010**

Answer (score 2):

И в белорусском, и в украинском и в современном русском языке(возможно - позднее) слово  ***"завзятый"*** является прямым заимствованием из польского,где ***zawzięty*** образовано от глагола ***zawzięć się*** – ***"заупрямиться"***).Польско-русский словарь дает нам одно значение для перевода слова ***zawzięty*** - ***"ярый"***. Синонимы можем подобрать сами(рьяный,истовый,упорный и т.д.).
  Отсюда рассуждения [[@grumant](/users/1349/grumant)](/users/1349/grumant)'а о родстве ***"завзятых"*** и ***"записных"*** становятся притянутыми.

[[@Валентин](/users/981/%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD)](/users/981/%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD) при цитировании  **В. В. Виноградов. История слов, 2010**  потерял букву ***ę*** в польском слове ***zawzięty***, что затруднило дальнейшие поиски. Следует быть точнее таких мелочах.

Comment: *to  @grumant*  По-моему автор вопроса интересовался больше происхождением слова, о чем я написал с ответе. По поводу его значения, точнее значений, можно продолжить отдельную дискуссию.